# How can I configure WebStorm to provide code completion for KoaJS?

Tags: webstorm, koa

Currently, WebStorm reports that KoaJS's methods are undefined. It's a minor, yet persistent annoyance. I've searched on the net and I've searched through WebStorm's configuration dialogs to no avail.

Does anyone use WebStorm with KoaJS and have intellisense/code completion working properly?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

It's a known bug, please follow [WEB-11299](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-11299) for updates

Answer (score 1):

Doing either `File > Settings > Languages & Frameworks > JavaScript > Libraries`
or `Click the face in the bottom right corner of the IDE > Libraries in scope`. You can `Add` new libraries that are used for highlighting and code completion. If you are using NPM it's handiest to just add the entire `node_modules` directory so WebStorm will know about any other packages you install. Or if you don't want to do that, or you don't use NPM, you can just add the `koa` directory.

Depending on how you create your project I think WebStorm can automatically add the `node_modules` directory. At least some of my projects have done so without me explicitly doing this.

A bit more reading: http://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2014/07/how-webstorm-works-completion-for-javascript-libraries/

Answer (score 1):

Mac Webstorm 2016.1.1

The following are valid：

Preferences -> Languages & Frameworks -> Javascript -> Libraries -> Download -> Typescript community stubs -> Find koa library -> Download and install -> Apply

[worked picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7bKLq.png)

Answer (score 0):

use `new koa()` instead(with typescript installed),worked for my Intellij IDEA 2016.3.4